# Where are these three songs from?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Can someone help me out and tell me where these three songs (the highlighted ones) are taken from? They've been transcribed for violin, but I would like to listen to the originals if possible.

[Song One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkC4Z.png)

[Song Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep4d1.jpg)

[Song Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BrvA.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to nail three totally, but I hope this is enough of an answer to get started with.

Going by the titles in the scans of the music, my inadequate Russian, and help from Google Translate :

Song one is a "Theme from the opera 'The Magic Flute'" by Mozart.
A bit vague as a title, but the opera as a whole is worth a listen. Opera is not my thing, but I can listen to "The Magic Flute". Later edit: It's the "Slaves' dance". Link to clip from the opera : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PecDdk73ph4&t=1m49s

Song two is "Soldier's March" by R.Schumann. From "Album for the young", a set of piano pieces. Opus 68 #2.

Song three is  "Evening Song"  ("AbendLied" German) by Mozart.

A few things which Song three is not : there are some youtube performances of something called "Evening song" by Mozart (for Violin duet, the ones I found), but they are not anything like this. Nor is it from "A little Night music" or "Evening thoughts of Laura".

Comment: I've taken a quick look through the Mayic Flute but can't find it in there. I might have to just listen to it all completely - opera isn't my thing either. The last piece I can't find anywhere.